# call Artisan command that has no name for the option

Tags: laravel

How would I execute command like this from the Controller?

Package I am  using that gives the below artisan commands: https://github.com/JosephSilber/page-cache

```
php artisan page-cache:clear {slug}
```

For example if typed manually:

```
php artisan page-cache:clear about-us
```

Laravel docs gives us this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

```
Artisan::call('email:send', [
    'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
]);
```

Since the artisan command page-cache:clear does not take any named parameters, how do I send the slug parameter to it?

I've tried this:

```
Artisan::call('page-cache:clear ' . $content->slug);
```

And get back this error:

> Command "page-cache:clear hem" is not defined.↵↵Did you mean this?↵    page-cache:clear

I've also tried this:

```
Artisan::call('page-cache:clear', [$content->slug]);
```

But then slug is not added and it calls `php artisan page-cache:clear` without slug so this package clears all the cached files.

Answer (score 3):

Add explicit `true` as the value of the `slug` parameter:

```
Artisan::call('page-cache:clear', [$content->slug => true]);
```

**Edit**

Actually the above might only work for `--name` parameters and you might need this instead:

```
Artisan::call('page-cache:clear', ['' => $content->slug]);
```

Comment: no the second one won't work, I did try it before you mentioned it and got errors I belive. For some reason, this worked: ['slug' => $content->slug]

Answer (score 3):

Try it 
`Artisan::call('page-cache:clear', ['slug' => $content->slug]);`